# Editing data from fetch response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```js
render(){
  let events = this.props.data.map(function(eventsData, index){
    return (
      <View style={Cstyles.postContainerEvent} key={index}>
        <View style={Cstyles.subPostContainer}>
          <Text style={Cstyles.postTitleEvent}>{eventsData.title}</Text>
          <Text style={Cstyles.objDescription}>{eventsData.description}</Text>
          <View style={Cstyles.postSubEvent}>
            <Text style={Cstyles.postSubCatEvent}>{eventsData.venue}</Text>
            <Text style={Cstyles.postSubCatEvent}>{eventsData.time}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={Cstyles.postSubEvent}>
            <Text style={Cstyles.postSubCatEventAddress}>{eventsData.address}</Text>
            <Text style={Cstyles.postSubCatEvent}>{eventsData.price}</Text>
            <Text style={Cstyles.postSubCatEventDate}>{eventsData.month + " " + eventsData.day}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  });
```

I'm getting this data using the Fetch API on a parent component. One of the objects received(eventsData.month) is a string from 1-12 depending on the month ex: I receive "12" for December. I want to turn the "12" into "December" and so on for the other months.

Comment: you want the name of the month?  or just a string containing `"12"`?

Comment: Sorry I let me rephrase that. I get "12" and want to turn into "Dec"

Comment: Moment.js (https://momentjs.com) is spectacular for for most manipulations of dates and times and day and month names in various formats.  Also very well thought-out and straightforward.  In anything but the simplest cases, give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Then do this

```
<Text style={Cstyles.postSubCatEventDate}>{moment(eventsData.month, "M").format("MMMM") + " " + eventsData.day}</Text>
```

This will turn a two digit number into a full month string. So '06' would become 'June'.

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised when I [failed to find a javascript native function to convert a number into a date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), so, not wanting to bring a framework into it, I used something like this:

Obviously, that's useful for anything but English, if you want the three letter versions.  But it doesn't pull in thousands of lines of framework, either :P

```js
var months = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"] ;

for( var i = 1; i <= 12; i++){
 document.body.innerHTML += "<p>" +  months[i-1] +"</p>"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Dan Farrell's answer. I'll note that you could also use an object for a bit more readability.

```js
var monthMap = {
  "1": "Jan",
  "2": "Feb",
  "3": "Mar",
  "4": "Apr",
  "5": "May",
  "6": "Jun",
  "7": "Jul",
  "8": "Aug",
  "9": "Sep",
  "10": "Oct",
  "11": "Nov",
  "12": "Dec",
}
document.body.innerHTML += monthMap["12"];
```

I'll also mention that, if you're willing to add an external library, `moment.js` is excellent and worth investigating. It does a lot more than just date formatting.